# Unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll for more information : login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I am writing a C# windows form, so when you click exit, it closes the
window, and when you click login, I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

It throws the error on the line

```
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC;Initial Catalog=STATFRET;User ID=sa;Password=***********");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) from db.UTILISATEURS where mat_utl='" + User_txt + "'  and   psw_utl='" + Pwd_txt + "'",con );

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
            this.Hide();
            Something s = new Something();
            s.Show();
    }
    else
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Veuillez remplir les cases");
    }

    try
    {
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your credentials are just incorrect.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like an error with your connection string if the message that you've used as title is given back to you. Have you checked your credentials? Maybe you try to connect with this credentials through Sql Server Management Studio, open the desired database and execute a select all.

The reason why you get this error when calling Fill() is because until then you never opened a connection. Maybe you can try to open the connection before calling *Fill()* on the datatable.

```
conn.Open();
```

Another tip to use the connection correctly:

Put it into a using Statement so that it gets disposed correctly.